# Force Hibernate to read database and not return cached entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I am using Hibernate and Spring for my web application.

In database operation, Hibernate is caching entities and returning them in next request without reading the actual database. I know this will reduce the load on database and improve performance.

But while this app still under construction, I need to load data from database in every request (testing reason).

**Is there any way to force database read?**

I became sure about the caching from this log4j message.

```
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'HelloController'
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-42] - Last-Modified value for [/myApp/../somePageId.html] is: -1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can disable the second-level cache of some certain entities in Hibernate without changing annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934133/how-i-can-disable-the-second-level-cache-of-some-certain-entities-in-hibernate-w)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`session.refresh(entity)` or `entityManager.refresh(entity)` (if you use JPA) will give you fresh data from DB.

Comment: i am not using JPA.  so do i need to change `session.get()` to `session.refresh()`?  or if there is a way to check if it is coming from cache .?

Comment: No, you should use `session.refresh()` after `session.get()` because it only works with attached entities. To check if an entity is already loaded, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473828/hibernate-session-contains-class-clazz-serializable-id) has some suggestions, but nothing reliable imho.

Comment: the trick with this approach is that when the entity does not exist in the database, but exists in the cache, calling `refresh()` throws `org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists`

Comment: @adamsiemion Yes, that is something one should be aware of.

Comment: I had the same problem described in the question. With JPA it seems that `entityManager.clear()` discard in a single operation the whole cache.

Comment: This isn't really satisfactory for retrieving multiple entities--won't refresh on every single one just create a separate query for each? I'd prefer if the initial query itself just bypassed the cache. I'm doing query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS)   ... but this doesn't seem to work either. Annoying cache!

Comment: You're using Hibernate, which implements JPA, meaning you use JPA.

Answer (score 23):

Do the read within a new transaction.

For example:

```
...
MyDTO myDTO = fetchMyDTOById(daoId);
...
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private MyDTO fetchMyDTOById(Long dtoId) {
    return repository.findById(dtoId);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Call refresh entity `session.refresh(entity)`

  ### or
- Open new session then call `session2.get(EntityClass.class,id)` it will pull the entity from the database

  ```
      Session session2=sessionFactory.openSession();                  
      EntityClass entity=(EntityClass) session2.get(EntityClass.class, id);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Please call EntityManger.clear() method, and then call repository.find() or repository.findOne() as per your requirement to select the updated data from database.

```
@PersistentContext EntityManager em;
@Autowired EntityReporisitory rep;
....
....
@Transactional
public void method(){
....
....
em.clear();// This line will clear the current value of entity
Entity e = rep.find(example);// In this line data will be loaded freshly from DB
....
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to ensure a cache miss. The 'counter' can be any unique value generator, such as a literal counter, or a time parameter or even a UUID. Expect a negative condition to be true.

E.g:

```
@Query("select p from Post p where p.id = :postId and p.postedOn <> :cacheBustingTimer")
Post fetchPostById(@Param("postId") Long postId, @Param("cacheBustingTimer") LocalDateTime cacheBustingTimer);
```

Sample call

```
Post post = postRepository.fetchPostById(postIdToFetch, LocalDateTime.now().minusYear(100));
```