# Spring test updates locally read JPA entity during transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-test, transactional

I have a Spring integrated test that is wrapped in `@Transactional`. The Hibernate/JPA database interface  extends `JpaRepository` and uses `PESSIMISTIC_READ` and `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` locks on its functions. Within the test, the following steps occur:

1. An `@Entity` object is read from the repo.
2. The target function runs, which updates and writes that same `@Entity` to the repo inside another `@Service`-level transaction.
3. That `@Entity` object is again read from the repo and compared to the first object.

The problem is that after writing in step 2, the first `@Entity` object has actually been updated locally. When comparing the `@Entity` objects in step 3, both are equal instead of having expected "before and after" differences.

How is this "syncing" of local `@Entity` objects happening, and is this expected behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "another `@Service`-level transaction"? Is the service method configured to require a **new** transaction (i.e., `REQUIRES_NEW`)?

Comment: If not, then the use case you describe is likely covered by this _note_ in the Spring Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-false-positives

Comment: @SamBrannen the service just uses the default `@Transactional`. Thanks for the reference, I'll look into that for my tests

Answer (score 1):

After some research using the right terms (e.g. caching in persistence context), it appears to be expected as described here:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries/

A viable workaround would be to manually refresh the entity or separate the 2 reads into different transactions, as mentioned here:
[Force hibernate to read database and not returning cached entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905148/force-hibernate-to-read-database-and-not-returning-cached-entity)